# I can not use the data point click event

Tags: jqplot

[image]

The second chart value is too small to click.
What should I do?

```js
$("#jqplot3").bind('jqplotDataClick',
  function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data){
   var url = "<c:url value='/test/salesDetailPage.do'/>" ;
      var target = "openPopup";
      var itemType = item[pointIndex];
    
    window.open("", "openPopup", "width=1500, height=800, left=600, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes");
           fn_openPopup(url, target, itemType);
  }
```

Comment: I would say that you better adjust the scale of the chart so you can actually see both values. But there is a huge difference between 10,842 and 14...

Comment: 1. Use log scaling. 2. Make a bigger click target so clicking near the value does the right thing.

Comment: I solved the problem using the log scaling. Thank you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838416/multi-axes-chart-with-normal-and-log-scale?rq=1